# Do all OpenID Connect Providers implement uniformly?

Tags: openid-connect

One of the challenges with using OAuth 2.0 is that the variability in the spec means that each provider implements OAuth a little differently.  If I want to write a consumer for OAuth I need to do some pretty specific coding for each provider I want to implement.

Would it be accurate to state that OpenID Connect is narrowly defined enough to avoid this trap?  Should a single, generic OIC consumer library be able to connect to any certified OIC provider without custom code for each provider?

Thanks in advance!

[edit] - grammar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using OAuth 2.0 for user authentication you run in to the trap that you describe, also documented here: http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/, i.e. every provider has to implement its own extension to make OAuth 2.0 fit that use case because OAuth 2.0 was not designed for user authentication or Web SSO.

But when using the OpenID Connect profile of OAuth 2.0 you will indeed be able to use a generic OpenID Connect Client/RP against arbitrary Providers for authenticating users, assuming both follow the spec. As an example of that, see: https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc

Comment: Thanks Hans, I'm writing up some client code to test now but it's good to hear I'm not on the wrong track.